# objective-c/cocoa place image in title bar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible to place an image in the title bar of an mac app?

Could anyone give me a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Walk up the view hierachy of the window's content view using superview and add your NSImageView there